# using setState to getState in setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I use this in a `setInterval` and it feels very illegal

```
const [nonce, setNonce] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  window.setInterval(() => {
    let nonce = 0;
    setNonce((prevNonce) => (nonce = prevNonce));
    console.log('nonce has the correct value even if got changed:', nonce);
  }, 10);
}, []);
```

Is this something I should not use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with it, but it needs to be cleaned up to avoid being re-rendered.

You have to store the variable and unset it on the return of your `useEffect` hook.

In other words, if you don't do that, every time you "change page" in your application, you will create an extra interval.

This is how you clear your interval:

```js
const [nonce, setNonce] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  // Store in a variable
  const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    let nonce = 0;
    setNonce((prevNonce) => (nonce = prevNonce));
    console.log('nonce has the correct value even if got changed:', nonce);
  }, 10);
  // Clear it on return
  return () => clearInterval(myInterval);
}, []);
```